# generate secure random bits

Tags: java, random, cryptography

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random ranGen = new SecureRandom();
    ranGen.setSeed(0);

    int randomNumber = ranGen.nextInt(2);

    System.out.print(randomNumber);
}
```

Is the above code a good way to either produce a truly random and secure/unbiased 0 or 1 ?

Comment: Don't call `setSeed`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos why not ? why is it used for ?

Comment: Yes, although your `setSeed` call is counterproductive (because `SecureRandom` adds another component to whatever seed you pass and passing a static value isn't a great idea). Also, why not use [`nextBoolean()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean%28%29)?

Comment: I'd use System.currentTimeMillis() for a seed, because it always is something else

Comment: guys, I still did not get why I would use a seed and why I would not. If i did not use, what is the default seed used ?

Comment: @codequestioneer Bad idea. 1) Time predictable and thus not secure 2) The default seed of `SecureRandom` is already much better.

Comment: @codequestioneer I read somewhere that alongside time, it uses various runnables and threads and lock timings in the processor... unsure tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't (a good way to either produce a truly random and secure/unbiased 0 or 1).

`new SecureRandom()` is OK, but setting the seed directly after isn't. Oracle's implementation of `"SHA1PRNG"` - which is normally the default - will *replace* the initial seed by the one given if `setSeed()` is called before any entropy is retrieved from the random number generator.

If it is not seeded the `SecureRandom` implementation will be seeded using an entropy source of the operating system. This should be relatively safe. Often the operating system is the only part that has access to real hardware devices so it is better positioned to retrieve entropy than the JVM. You can call `setSeed()`, but you should only call it after a call to `nextBytes()`, requesting at least one byte. Afterwards you can *add* some seed to the pool.

Finally, calling `nextInt(2)` is OK, but not very efficient. It will request 32 bits, and then toss away the 31 bits it doesn't require. Requesting random bytes and extracting the bits from the array will be more efficient (if efficiency is required, don't over-optimize). Calling `nextBoolean()` will probably just toss away 7 bits, so it is at least 4 times more efficient and much more concise.

Comment: Maarten, thanks a lot for this in detail explanation. I highly appreciate your time.